# Read on access does not work / how to assign model values through the controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

I've followed [this awesome tutorial by Dana Mulder](https://medium.com/@danamulder/tutorial-create-a-simple-messaging-system-on-rails-d9b94b0fbca1) on how to write a simple messaging service in rails.  For example the "Messege read" function.

if you access a message it should write the value of `message.read` from `false` to `true` but it doesn't. I've searched the web on how to assign values through the controller but none worked.

Unfortunately it's not possible just to `@message.last.read = true;`. I think its a key feature to be able to show users at every time if they got an unread message and to highlight them.

Do you have experiences with Dana Mulder's attempt on how to write a messenger and know the answer to this?

Comment: Post actual code that doesnt work, also your code `@message.last.read = true` while in the tutorial `@messages.last.read = true`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `@messages.last.read = true` to `@messages.last.update(read: true)`

Comment: Thank you very much, that worked. could i have that found in the official rails reference? i dont like asking stupid questions.

Comment: No problem, you assigned the value to the object but never saved it, hence the value you assigned was lost at the end of the request.

Comment: i referenced you under the medium post of dana mulder because i wasnt the only one asking for a solution. thanks again!

Comment: Thanks, @GabrielTheCoder - appreciate it!